# How to make Typescript recognize properties created with the "get properties ()" method in Lit-Element?

Tags: typescript, lit-element

When creating a Component with LitElement we can use the `@property` decorator or the static `properties` field, as described in the [documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties).

I'd like to use this second method with Typescript, but it complains as the field does not exist in the class.

```js
export class MyClass extends LitElement {

  static get properties() { 
    return { 
      greeting: {type: String},
    };
  }

  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.greeting = "test"; // Error: Property 'greeting' does not exist on type 'MyClass'
  }
}
```

Typescript complains the greeting property does not exist. How can I make Typescript recognize properties created with the "get properties ()" method in Lit-Element?

**Why?**

I want to be able to avoid repetition by using the spread operator. Something like this:

```js
const obj = {/** Long object definition **/};

export class MyClass extends LitElement {

  static get properties() { 
    return {
      ...obj,
      greeting: {type: String},
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution regarding this problem?

From the docs I just found to use the @property decorator instead.

Source: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#declare

Comment: Unfortunatelly my solution was to type all the fields both as class fields and within the properties method. Using the @property was not an option for me because of other tools used in the project. I ende up giving the attempt to avoid repetition. :(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the decorators, but you still need to declare the class property, as you would if you weren't using Lit at all. The `properties` getter isn't a substitute for the class property declaration, it's just another way of passing the property configuration/metadata to `LitElement`.

(Also `type` in the configuration isn't a TypeScript thing, it's just telling Lit which default attribute converter to use when mapping your element attribute to a class property.)

You can do this:

```js
export class MyClass extends LitElement {
  greeting: string;

  static get properties() { 
    return { 
      greeting: {type: String},
    };
  }

  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.greeting = "test";
  }
}
```

or in this case you can skip the constructor completely:

```js
export class MyClass extends LitElement {
  greeting = "test";

  static get properties() { 
    return { 
      greeting: {type: String},
    };
  }
}
```